# Update table using data from other tables (normalization)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert

I have doubt to mount a query to update and / or add data in a table.

I have a table1 that will be supplied with the following rules:

The **table1** have the same **fields** of **table2** + **status** field to show if the register is active ("A") or inactive ("I").

For each record in table1, check if there are new records in table2

**If the record exists in table2 and the record doens't exist in table1**, includes the information in table 1 - all the fields of that record from table2 + character "A" (active) in the status field.

**If the record exists in table2 and the record exists in table1 too**, I have to compare id_register from table2 with the id_register from table1

**If any data in this row  is different**, I have to insert a new row in table1 - all fields from the table2 + character "A" (active) in the *status field* -, **AND** the line that was different in table1 will be update with a character "I" (inactive) in *status field*;

**If the record was deleted in table2**, this row will receive character "I" (inactive) in table1 status field. (Deleted Record = I have to verify the records that exists in table1 and doens't exists in table2)

The records that have no changed will not be updated.

The tables:

### table1

id_register
name
address
phone
email
date
value
status

### table2

id_register
name
address
phone
email
date
value

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to log changes to your tables.  This is quite doable using triggers but I would suggest against that for a couple reasons.  First, your most recent record will always be your active one in table 2, so using a timestamp avoids the update.

Secondly rather than building a solution yourself, I would recommend a module I have used in the past, namely [tablelog](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/).  It will be much simpler than trying to re-implement it all yourself.  Also more eyeballs and all of that....